# VideoView to play video but reloading

Tags: android

```
vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); 
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.start();
```

I use VideoView to play an url video.
like above.
But while I change th phone screenOrientation.
It will reload all video.
How to improve the program to the reloading action?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: (In most case this works..)

Modifies your VideoView xml file something like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Solution 2..

Or Handle orientation change in your activity,

For activity tag of video in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

So the whole line would look like this:

```
<activity android:name="<Your video avtivityy>" android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

And then add the following method to this activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     // stuff for set video to proper position..
}
```

And let me know what happen...

Comment: Whenever your devices runtime changes occurs which you mentioned in manifest file then you can configure those changes for your application. To do that you have to implement this override onConfigurationChanged() in your activity.

Comment: should i put my videoview in that onConfigurationChanged part to retain the video playback.